# XMLHttpRequest detect new data from server before res.end()

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to detect new data from the server as it is sent? For example, with express.js:

```
res.write('Processing 14% or something');
```

and then display that on the page with a progress bar.

#### Edit:

My original question was a bit confusing so let me explain the situation. I have created a page where users can upload song files. These files are then converted (using ffmpeg) to .ogg and .mp3 files for the web. The conversion takes a long time. Is it possible to send real time data about the conversion back to the client using the same XMLHttpRequest that sent the files?

Comment: Can you describe more about the problem you're trying to solve?  Are you trying to show progress on a long running ajax call?  Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are trying to implement event based actions. Yes node.js has got some excellent web socket libraries such as [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) and [sack.js](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)

You need to understand nodejs [event driven](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/part-1-understanding-event-loops-writing-great-code-11401.html) pattern.

Websocket protocol helps maintain full duplex connection between server and client. You can notify clients when any action happens in server and similar you can notify server when any action happens in client. Libraries provide flexibility to broadcast event to all connected client or selected ones.

So it is basically **emit** and **on** that you will be using often.
Go through the documentation, it will not take much time to learn. Let me know if you need any help.